# Guess the number Feedback Please

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning Python these days and made my first code. Guess_The_Number and I would like some comments to improve or if I am on the right track. Thank you very much in advance
P.s: I am trying to create my own function.

```py
def guess_number (answer):
    trys = 0
        
    while trys < 5:
        guessing = int(input("Your guessing is? "))
        if guessing == answer:
            print ("Yes!! it's Right!!")
            break
        elif guessing < answer:
            print ("Big")
        elif guessing > answer:
            print ("smaller")
        trys = trys+1
        
    if trys == 5:
        print("WoW, your trys are over  , try again!!")
        print("The number was ", answer)
    
print("Welcome to guess the number!!")
print("You have 5 trys to guess the number")
print("Good Luck!!")
print("I'm thiking in a number from 0 to 100")
print('')
import random
num_right = random.randint(0,100)
guess_number(num_right)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might seem a bit much, but I'm reviewing this as if it were intended for production code:

1. `black` and `isort` can reformat this code to be more idiomatic without changing the functionality.
2. `pylint`, `flake8` or both can tell you of some issues with this code:

   ```
   $ pylint --disable=missing-function-docstring,missing-module-docstring q.py 
   ************* Module q
   q.py:3:0: C0303: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
   q.py:14:0: C0303: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
   q.py:6:8: R1723: Unnecessary "elif" after "break" (no-else-break)
   q.py:23:0: C0413: Import "import random" should be placed at the top of the module (wrong-import-position)

   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Your code has been rated at 8.26/10
   ```
3. The plural of "try" is "tries".
4. `trys += 1` is syntactic sugar for `trys = trys + 1`.
5. The code mixes I/O (`input`/`print`) and logic, which generally makes the code harder to maintain. It might be better to split this into two functions, one to check the answer against the right answer, and one to receive input and print output.
6. To enable reuse of the code I would add a `main` function and the idiomatic

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```

   lines at the bottom of the script to actually run it. Basically, if you just import your file into another nothing should print when importing it. Right now it's impossible to import cleanly from the script:

   ```
   $ python
   Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 13 2020, 11:55:53) 
   [GCC 10.2.0] on linux
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import q
   Welcome to guess the number!!
   You have 5 trys to guess the number
   Good Luck!!
   I'm thiking in a number from 0 to 100

   Your guessing is?
   ```

Comment: thanks for the feedback,I'm yet a beginner and have some terms i never see before like 'isort', but i search in google so no problem. I have many things to improve and work. thanks again i'll try to apply your tips ^_^.

Answer (score 2):

**I suggest to refactor it as follows:**

```
import random

def guess_number (answer):
    for num_tries in range(5):
        try:
            guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        except:
            break
        if guess < answer:
            print ("Too low")
        elif guess > answer:
            print ("Too high")
        else:
            print ("Yes! It's right!")
            return
    
    print("Wow, your guesses are over!")
    print(f"The number was {answer}")
   
print("Welcome to guess the number!")
print("You have 5 tries to guess the number")
print("Good Luck!")
print("I'm thinking of a number from 0 to 100")

my_num = random.randint(0, 100)
guess_number(my_num)
```

**Below are some comments on your code:**

````
def guess_number (answer):
    # Needs a better name. Also, plural of try is tries:
    trys = 0
        
    while trys < 5:
        # guess is a better name.
        guessing = int(input("Your guessing is? "))
        if guessing == answer:
            print ("Yes!! it's Right!!")
            # change to return:
            break
        elif guessing < answer:
            # Improve the message - it is not clear:
            print ("Big")
        elif guessing > answer:
            print ("smaller")
        # Use a for loop instead, which combines incrementing 
        # and < 5 check:
        trys = trys+1
        
    # It is 5 anyway, after the while loop exits. Remove this if:
    if trys == 5:
        print("WoW, your trys are over  , try again!!")
        # Use an f-string instead:
        print("The number was ", answer)
    
print("Welcome to guess the number!!")
print("You have 5 trys to guess the number")
print("Good Luck!!")
print("I'm thiking in a number from 0 to 100")
print('')
# import should be at the top:
import random
# use a better name:
num_right = random.randint(0,100)
guess_number(num_right)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

What I have to add here, is that you should always validate/sanitize user input.

```
guessing = int(input("Your guessing is? "))
```

Converting plain user input to an `int`, without checking, is prone to cause problems.  I would suggest creating an `isInteger(something: str)` (something will always be a string) function to validate that.

```py
def safeInt(something: str): # maybe you could be more creative with that name
    """ If `something` can be converted to an int return that otherwise reutrn False """
    try:
        return int(something)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

And now, you can keep asking the user again, if their `input` is incorrect

```
while trys < 5:
    guessing = input("Your guessing is? ")
    # Keep asking until you get a valid response
    while type(guessing := safeInt(guessing)) != int: # walrus operator 
        guessing = input("You did not enter a valid int. Your guessing is? ")
    # Once this point is reached `guessing` will be an `int`.
    # guessing := safeInt(guessing) sets guessing = safeInt(guessing) 
    # and evaluates `type(safeInt(guessing)) != int` at the same time
```

On a side note, `if trys == 5` is redundant. That is, because it comes after `while trys < 5` which will exit once `tries >= 5` and because you are incrementing by `1`, when the loop breaks, `trys` will be exactly `5`. So it is safe to say, that you can remove that `if` statement.

Comment: Good concept, except rather than a function with a return type of `Union[int, Literal[False]]` I'd prefer to just catch `ValueError` in the function with the `input` call.